# How do I find a printer who can print in white on a t-shirt?

Tags: print-design, print-production, white, apparel

Where can I find a printing company that can print my logo on a  heat transfer using " WHITE"  I am trying to put my logo (that has white clouds in it ) on a t-shirt. BUT , I cannot find anyone who can print the transfer for me. Where are the people that own a OKI printer that now prints in white?

Comment: Hey Bill, can you clarify your question a little? Do you mean printing with white ink? Or printing on a white base?

Comment: I doubt you can achieve this with the technique you're talking about (transfer) because it's usually a process that overprint the transfer over the material. There are transfers that are opaque though but also require commercial equipment to apply them on the t-shirts because they're thicker; the best is to find a t-shirt printing provider & ask for it or call clothes manufacturers & ask for their providers. But if you were looking for a "do-it-yourself" kind of solution, that might not work for you. To get white ink on a t-shirt, you'll probably need to use real serigraphy or screen printing

Comment: I'm confused, most transfer material IS white... so when your transfer is printed any white should be the transfer itself showing not any "ink".

Comment: Short run/one-off? Try Avery (03279)?

Comment: I mean printing with white ink , check out http://www.signwarehouse.com/blog/uninet-icolor-500-laser-transfer-printer/ this new printer link

Comment: Bill, you should try to contact Jerry (the dude who wrote that post) and see if he knows of anyone in the US who has that printer yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason for not using screenprint? That will do white perfectly fine, and likely hold up better than the heat transfer method.

Comment: Yes, but a self Weeding one page transfer is MUCH cheaper. I'm trying to get just a few samples and don't want to invest 250 plus dollars to get 6 shirts. Thanks for your input !

Comment: I dont know where you're getting your prices from. A quick search for "T-shirt screen printing" for almost any city will yield very affordable prices for anything from a one-off to hundreds/thousands.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want some alternative ways like Screen printing (which is amazing) you might want to check specifically for print stores that do DTG printing, and that is the **Direct-to-garment** method.

Comment: Thanks for that advise, I didn't think of that and that would be a good alternative. There is a new OKI printer that is coming to USA that is designed to make transfers with White, it will also do many other things like rhinestone and mettallic. see this link http://www.signwarehouse.com/blog/uninet-icolor-500-laser-transfer-printer/